# Spring-data-neo4j-4 How to specify more than one label in @NodeEntity annotation

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I need more than one Label for my entities . Is there a way to specify it in annotation or any other way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment, node entities can have [multiple labels only via inheritance](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#__nodeentity_the_basic_building_block). For example, if you have a Person class with Employee extending it, the Employee entity will have both Person and Employee labels.

Comment: Will there be another way in future releases ?